# NSFetchedResultsController: Get section object

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've used an NSFetchedResultsController to group my subcategories into their respective main categories and implemented a custom header:

My fetch:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"SubCategory"];

    NSSortDescriptor *mainCatPosition = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"belongsToMainCategory.position" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *subCatPosition = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES];

    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mainCatPosition,subCatPosition,nil];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"display = %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [self.db.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                       managedObjectContext:self.budgetDatabase.managedObjectContext
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"belongsToMainCategory.position"
                                                                                  cacheName:nil];
```

My custom header:

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    SectionHeader *header=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SectionHeader" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    MainCategory *mainCategory = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    //Icon
    UIImage *icon;
    if(!mainCategory.icon){
        icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultIcon.png"];
    } else {
        icon = [UIImage imageNamed:mainCategory.icon];
    }
    header.categoryIcon.image = icon;
    header.sectionBackgroundImage.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"content-bkg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];

    return header;
}
```

But I guess this: MainCategory *mainCategory = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section]; 
is wrong? How can I access this mainCategory object with all its properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`sections`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchedResultsController/sections) array of a NSFetchedResultsController contains objects of some class that confirms to the [`NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo) protocol. There are not NSManagedObjects in the sections array.
If you think about it that makes sense, because your fetch is not always sectioned along other objects, more often the fetch is sectioned by NSDates, NSStrings, NSNumbers or whatever.

You could probably get a `SubCategory` object from the section, and then get the `MainCategory` from this subCategory. Something like this:

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section];

if ([sectionInfo numberOfObjects] > 0) {
    SubCategory *subCategory = [sectionInfo objects][0];
    MainCategory *mainCategory = subCategory.belongsToMainCategory;

    ....
}
else {
    // empty section... whatever
}
```